# flicking for MainForm

Tags: c#

I have login form and a mainForm.

After loading MainForm, it will be hidden and load the LoginForm. If the user enters correct authentication then the loginForm will be disposed and the MainForm is shown. But the mainForm got flicks for the first time loading for several seconds.

I am implementing in C#.

How can I avoid this flicks?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the mainForm perform any animations when you open it up? If it does, it might help setting the forms `DoubleBuffered` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You should show the LoginForm before creating the MainForm, in `Program.Main()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't need to load MainForm before LoginForm appears, you can use this:

```
if (new LoginForm().ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```